# Convention for React keys for mapped arbitrary strings

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Per [React documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html),

> A “key” is a special string attribute you need to include when creating lists of elements.

Most array-like data have "natural" keys in the form of a unique identifier. However, when working with arbitrary strings, this isn't the case.

Consider this use case (which I've run into many times): an API response or other external source returns a string with newline characters. You want to render each line as its own `<p>` element.

```
render() {
  const text = 'Hello\nworld';
  return text.split('\n').map((line) => (<p>{line}</p>));
}
```

Each `<p>` needs a key. The most obvious non-index key is `line`, but it is not necessarily unique. The input could very well be `'Hello\nHello\nworld\nHello`.

The only reasonable option seems to be using the array index as a key, but it is widely accepted that this is poor practice: see [Index as a key is an anti-pattern](https://medium.com/@robinpokorny/index-as-a-key-is-an-anti-pattern-e0349aece318) and there is even a very popular ESLint rule [react/no-array-index-key](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/no-array-index-key.md) to enforce this.

What is the key convention in this scenario? I'm tempted to use the index as a key and disable the ESLint rule, but this feels like an absolute last resort.

Comment: you can use a separate library like "uuidv4" to generate random unique keys.

Comment: Randomly generating keys during each render defeats the purpose of the key altogether. See: https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/1342#issuecomment-39230939